# How i do not let my sum add the first sum?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sum, scanf

So i want my code actualy had different sum each cases, but the sum keep adding from the other cases, like for example the cases 2 sum are sum from loop 2nd + cases 1, the  cases 4 sum are sum from cases 1,2,3 and loop number 4 
[the Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0J5N.png)

```
`
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int cases;
    int day;
    int animal;
    int n;
    int a;
    int sum = 0;
    animal = 0;

    printf("Enter cases \n ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    for (cases = 0; cases < n; cases++)
    {
        printf("cases #%d\n", cases+1);
        printf("Enter how many days.\n");
        scanf(" %d", &a);
    

        for(day=1;day<=a;){
            printf("Enter how many animal that you capture at day #%d\n", day);
            scanf(" %d", &animal);
            day++;
            sum = sum + animal;

        }
        animal = 0;
        day = 1;
        printf("cases#%d = %d\n", cases + 1, sum);
    }


    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is. If there's n error, show it.

Comment: ahh okay i'll try

Comment: @interjay ahh sometimes when i wrote 3 cases it run until 10, and it somehow read the scanf first in the 1st for then it reads the print in the 1st for, and sometimes I can't run the code because it says the linking are error

Answer (score 1):

**You need to return `sum` to 0 in every case**

Put `sum=0;` under `for (cases...`